React state not updating in nested event handler
Please consider the following code:
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const OtherComponent = ({ locked }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{position: 'fixed'}}>
      {locked ? 'Locked' : 'Unlocked'}
    </div>
  );
}

const PageComponent = () => {
  const [locked, setLocked] = useState(false);
  const mainRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollListener, {passive: true});
  }, [])

  const scrollListener = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);

    setLocked(true);

    mainRef.current.addEventListener('wheel', wheelEventListener, {passive: true});
  }

  const wheelEventListener = () => {
    // locked always === false here, expecting true
    console.log('locked: ', locked);
  }

  return (
    <div ref={mainRef} style={{height: "5000px"}}>
      <OtherComponent locked={locked} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default PageComponent;


I don't get why locked is not true in wheelListener/why the state is not updated. I could use a reference instead of a state var, but then OtherComponent wouldn't update. Only way I have found to make this work is to use a state AND a ref. Pretty ugly. Any suggestions?

Do you want the wheel event listener to be added once the "locked" state is true? Would you want it to be removed once the locked state goes back to false?

A rule of thumb is that event listeners, once added, create a closure where state changes are not registered.  If you need an event listener to handle a fresh value of state, then you need to remove and re-add the event listener when state updates.

@ScottZ Yes and perhaps to answer your questions. You've got me thinking though. Do you have a solution?

@Rooster242 Question: are you trying to recreate a sticky element?

Due to how closures work in JS, the callback functions for eventlisteners as well as timeouts and intervals will hold onto the original value of state even if state has subsequently been updated.  Stale state in evenlistener/timeout/interval callbacks is a common issue with react.
With event listeners the only way for the callback function to have a fresh value of state is to remove then re-add the event listener when state updates.
This pattern here is how we can make sure an event listener always has the current value for state.
const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState("hello")

useEffect(()=>{
  function handleEvent(){
  console.log(myValue)
  }
document.addEventListener("onScroll", handleEvent)
return()=>{
  document.revmoveEventListener("onScroll", handleEvent)
  }
},[myValue])


When the component mounts the event listener is added.  Then every time myValue updates the event listener is remove, then re-added with the fresh state.
So, in the code you have provided we can do something like this.
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const OtherComponent = ({ locked }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: 'fixed' }}>{locked ? 'Locked' : 'Unlocked'}</div>
  );
};

const PageComponent = () => {
  const [locked, setLocked] = useState(false);
  const mainRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollListener, { passive: true });
  }, []);

  const scrollListener = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);
    setLocked(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (locked) {
      mainRef.current.addEventListener('wheel', wheelEventListener, {
        passive: true,
      });
    }
    return () => {
      mainRef.current.removeEventListener('wheel', wheelEventListener);
    };
  }, [locked]);

  const wheelEventListener = () => {
    // locked always === false here, expecting true
    console.log('locked: ', locked);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={mainRef} style={{ height: '5000px' }}>
      <OtherComponent locked={locked} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageComponent;

In this implementation, when locked changes to false we have a useEffect that will add the wheel event listener.  Then if locked changes back to true we will remove the event listener.
In your scenario we are only listening to a boolean value, so our add/remove logic is simple.  But if state was a another sort of primitive, or an array/object then the logic for when to add the event listener might be a bit more complex.
